# reposition a jquery element in html/css

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I reposition a jQuery element inside of a chosen image in HTML/CSS?

Below is the HTML I am using. The part that needs to be moved is "watch-text" which includes "watch-text-first" and "watch-text-second". The goal of this is to have the center of the watch display the numbers (188 and 12/17).

However, I need the text color & background color entry boxes of the element to remain below the watch.

I feel like I've tried everything as far as repositioning the divs are concerned. I'm really lost on this one; help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="watchcontainer">

<div class="watch-background">
<div class="watch-text" id="move">
  <div class="watch-text-first">188</div>
  <hr />
  <div class="watch-text-second">12/17</div>
   </div>
    <div id="cubicleface"><img src="images/cubicle.png" alt="cubicle" /></div>

  </div>

  <div class="watch-form-container">
<form id="watch-form" method="post" action="#">
  <label class="text-label">TEXT COLOR:</label><BR /><input type="text" class="input-text-color" size="25" value="#333333" /><br />
  <label class="text-label">BACKGROUND COLOR:</label><BR /><input type="text" class="input-bg-color" size="25" value="#FFFFFF" /><br />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="CUSTOMIZE" />
</form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please get http://jsfiddle.net/ account and set everything up after you are done post your link please.

Comment: Hard to say without a fiddle to look at - and no image to see. I'm assuming the image is a watch face? If that is the case you can either position your divs over the image by using a higher `z-index` value, or you can set the face image as a `background-url` value and put the divs inside of your `cubicleface` div?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nicoleb428/8VzQf/1/embedded/result/

Comment: I just now opened a JS Fiddle account & I really don't know how to utilize it correctly. Hopefully the info in the link is comprehendible.

Comment: And yes, the image is a watch face.

Comment: Please fix the links to images in your jsfiddle.net, they are needed to comprehend your questions and as a result help you.